# Create folder with UI Google Drive Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api, folderbrowserdialog

I want to be able to choose and/or create a new folder in Google Drive using UI for the user and also save that folder id for later use.

Right now I'm using:

```
IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Startar UI");
        startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentSender, 5, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
    }
}
```

It works but it's not ideal for the purpose.
The only other newActivityBuilder I could find was createFile which have the same problems.

Is there any workarounds for making this work?

Comment: I believe you are using the right API, try setting the mimeType on the activity to "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" to allow selecting a folder. Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html#setMimeType(java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 0):

Use EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID to get the DriveId from the result.(https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html#EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case 5:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          DriveId driveId =
              (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```